# Excel Auto filling with text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

I’m working on our taxes for a taxi business I just started. I run into a lot of the same addresses but it’s tough to remember all of the area codes for them, we only have 3 different areas as far as our borough taxes go and would like to auto fill column "I" in an Excel sheet to whatever the address is in column "G".

I saw a similar question but it seemed to more pertain to numbers. For a more descriptive example if the address in column "G" is "123 Sesame Street" then I’d like column "I" to auto input the value "NY". Thank you!

P.S. I believe I have the newest version of Excel. I can’t find exactly which one I have since I’m also new to Windows 10 but it came with the computer.

Comment: Build (address prefix - area code) table on separate worksheet and use VLOOKUP().

Comment: How is the desired value `"NY"` of column `I` defined? When will it be `"NY"`? You can have an auto-insert value like `"NY"` in column `I`, but that is based on a definition of possible inputs in column `G` - to me, it seems like you'd have to define a list of all adresses belonging to `"NY"`, to get the auto-insert working. And that doesn't seem to be a practical solution. Maybe you can use other criterias to define the auto-insert rule? sometzing like ZIP-Codes, maybe? At least i guess that it would be so much easier to define a list of ZIP-Codes and insert in column `G`based on that.

Answer (score 0):

So G would ultimately look like “123 Sesame Street New York, NY, 10128” so in column I we have 3 different taxed boroughs... it’s really tricky because if it’s outside of a taxable area then it’s only 3% instead of the 6% in town. The hard part though is that the towns will still be in the address. Looking up zip codes isn’t accurate for this scenario... so I’ve been going through every single address looking it up in the borough webpage and then essentially repeating the process for the next month. I’d like to just build an excel document so when I paste in a taxi log it can auto fill at least a majority of all the regular pick ups then I can just look up the new addresses and build from there.

Comment: This appears to be additional information about your question. In that case, you should edit it into the question rather than posting it as an answer.